# Django: Get value of foreign key field without additional SQL to DB

Tags: django, django-queryset

Model

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    doc_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='specialist/', default='', null=True, blank=True, max_length=250)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='photos')
```

I query the photos

```
temp = Photo.objects.all()
```

Now I want the ID of doctor that is saved in doctor field (for first element)

```
print(temp[0].doctor)
```

and I receive the Doctor object.
But I want the numeric ID. How can I get that?

I am aware that I can get it with

```
temp[0].doctor.id
```

but this will submit another query to the DB that I want to avoid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you add a `ForeignKey`, you actually have constructed two attributes:

- `fieldname` that is a reference to the related instance; and
- `fieldname_id` which is the real database column, and this stores a primary key of the table it refers to.

So you can write:

```
temp[0].doctor_id
```

In case you are only interested in the `doctor_id`, and not in other fields, you can make the query more efficient with `values_list`:

```
Photo.objects.values_list('doctor_id', flat=True).first()
```

In fact if you use `values_list`, you can use `doctor` here directly as field, and it will *only* return the identifier, not the corresponding `Doctor` instance:

```
# equivalent to values_list with doctor_id
Photo.objects.values_list('doctor', flat=True).first()
```

Comment: Thanx. _id was the perfect solution. I need the object, not values.

Comment: @caliph: well then the first solution is the way to go. I only added the second part, in case you, or somebody else would later only be interested in a certain column.

Comment: @caliph: well in the case of a many-to-many field, there is a table for the many-to-many field, so it is not fetched with the first query. If you thus have a model `A` with a m2m to `B`, then there is a table `a_b` in the db that contains the `id`s for `a` and `b`, and that table is not queried, unless you really need it.

Comment: ah, in order to loop through my list and avoid sending a query in each iteration I will have to add .select_related('m2m-attribute'), right?